# How did Thor and Rocket travel in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* we saw War Machine, Nebula, Black Widow, and Hawkeye brought the Benatar with them so they can fly to Morag and Soulworld.

However, the Thor and Rocket team is able to teleport to Asgard right away, without seemingly using Stormbreaker's Bifrost. How did they travel?

Comment: Actually they travel through the Quantum Realm to Morag, and Hawkeye/Widow travel onwards from there in the Benatar to Vormir...

Answer (score 5):

### Through the Quantum Realm

It's established in *Endgame* that you can travel **anywhere in space and/or time** through the Quantum Realm *provided* you have some form of ability to navigate it.

Tony invents a Time/Space GPS so our heroes can do exactly that.

Asgard is in space so they can travel to it via the Quantum Realm.

Comment: Is Vormir very had to find or something of the sort? Why did they need Nebula to key in the coordinated on the Benatar? Coulnd't they have used the GPS to get to Vormir too?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: @MovieMe I think that has been asked as a separate question already; if not it would make a good question. It seems that within their technology, they could have just transported Nat and Clint directly there instead.

Comment: @MovieMe See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212007/why-did-these-avengers-travel-together) on [scifi.se]

Comment: @DavidK, thanks for the link. I believe there is an assumption in the answer. The quantum tunnel machine does not define the destination. The travellers use the GPS to go where need to. Eg Steve and Tony decide to go from 2012 New York to 1970 New Jersey - both time and space travel.

Comment: There's obviously some localization effects going on, because e.g. New Jersey was not in the same place in 1970 and 2012, because the *Earth* was not in the same place.  It's rotating around its axis, revolving around the sun, which itself is orbiting the center of the galaxy, which is flying away from the center of the universe...  Tony's time/space GPS obviously has the ability to keep track of all that somehow.