# How does Captain America travel to other planets?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Endgame* we see Captain America returns to the past, to return the Infinity Stones.

But what's not quite clear is how he returns the Stones from other planets.

Does he bring a method of transportation with him, like earlier in the film, or does something else happen?

Comment: Same way they retrieved it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Thor and Rocket go there in "Avengers: Endgame"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100475/how-did-thor-and-rocket-go-there-in-avengers-endgame)

Comment: @Paulie_D this cannot be a duplicate. Captain America only ever makes one trip through the quantum realm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presumed that by using the Quantum Realm, he could travel through space and time (as Thor and Rabbit did to get to Asgard, and posing the question as to why they needed to take the Benetar with them at all?), so the *when* and *where* are sorted, but for me, the *how* is never answered.

How did he get the Space Stone back into the Tesseract in 1970? How did he inject the Aether into Jane Foster on Asgard? How did he get the Mind Stone back into the scepter in New York in 2012, or the Power Stone into the orb on Morag? The Time Stone is sorted, he just gives it back to the Ancient One, but the Soul Stone? Awkward moment with Red Skull and the subsequent "no returns or refunds" conversation regarding Natasha.

He doesn't seem to be carrying much equipment when he leaves, aside from a case which presumably contains the 'raw' stones.

Comment: If he goes to the Ancient One first then she can probably use the Time Stone to revert the others into their containers. The Aether is still going to be tricky to deal with though.

Comment: Me thinks this alone, warrants another Captain America film all based around Rogers returning the stones.

Comment: The case holds the stones, yes.  The scene includes a shot of what's inside the case, and it's the stones.  I do forget the exact visuals on the stones, but I think the aether/reality stone was in the same syringe-thing Rocket retrieved it with, at least.

Comment: Nobody said that he will return the stones in the same state to the same place. Bruce Banner only suggests to return them to the same time.

Answer (score -3):

If the question is how does he move in space from one point to another, remember that he have the tesseract/space stone with him.

All he need to do is to return the tesseract last, and as it happens, it's exactly in the right time and place to stay with his girlfriend.

Comment: There's no indication that Cap knows or can use any of the Stones.